# Why is a copy constructor used in a vector<map<unique_ptr>>?

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics

Consider the following code (see it [on Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/U6uDDc)):

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>> test;
    test.resize(2);
}
```

It's successfully compiled by GCC 9 and Clang 10, but MSVC 19.24 fails with the following errors:

```
C:/data/msvc/14.24.28314/include\xmemory(671): error C2280: 'std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>::pair(const std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
C:/data/msvc/14.24.28314/include\utility(168): note: see declaration of 'std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>::pair'
C:/data/msvc/14.24.28314/include\utility(168): note: 'std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>::pair(const std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>> &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)'
C:/data/msvc/14.24.28314/include\memory(1912): note: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
C:/data/msvc/14.24.28314/include\xtree(358): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,_Ty &)' being compiled
```

As I understand the error message, for some reason `std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<int>>` needs to be copied. I suppose it's because `std::map` has to be copied in case of a reallocation.

But why? Doesn't `std::map` have a move constructor? Is it a bug in MSVC? Or are both GCC and Clang wrong?

Comment: Them thing that gets me here is `resize is supposed to [default-insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) the elements into the vector.  Looks like MSVC might be making copies instead so that might indeed be a bug.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not limited to default-construction if relocation happens which is a runtime condition. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53527682/3953764) is an exact duplicate, but I'm not sure if I was correct.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki looks pretty good to me (in summary, the `std::map` is not required by the standard to be nothrow-movable, and if the library implementation does not go beyond this minimum spec, the vector.resize must cater to fallback to copy-construction)